# Project Euler #11 logic

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, algorithm, multidimensional-array

I have started to play around with Project Euler, however i hit a roadblock at [problem 11](https://projecteuler.net/problem=11)

> What is the greatest product of four adjacent numbers in the same
>   direction (up, down, left, right, or diagonally) in the 20×20 grid?`

There probably is a bug in my logic somewhere but even after multiple breaks and new approaches, i still have had no success.

The correct output should be 70600674 but i get 51267216.

This is more of an educational question, I would like to at least know where i messed up.

input.txt:

```
08 02 22 97 38 15 00 40 00 75 04 05 07 78 52 12 50 77 91 08
49 49 99 40 17 81 18 57 60 87 17 40 98 43 69 48 04 56 62 00
81 49 31 73 55 79 14 29 93 71 40 67 53 88 30 03 49 13 36 65
52 70 95 23 04 60 11 42 69 24 68 56 01 32 56 71 37 02 36 91
22 31 16 71 51 67 63 89 41 92 36 54 22 40 40 28 66 33 13 80
24 47 32 60 99 03 45 02 44 75 33 53 78 36 84 20 35 17 12 50
32 98 81 28 64 23 67 10 26 38 40 67 59 54 70 66 18 38 64 70
67 26 20 68 02 62 12 20 95 63 94 39 63 08 40 91 66 49 94 21
24 55 58 05 66 73 99 26 97 17 78 78 96 83 14 88 34 89 63 72
21 36 23 09 75 00 76 44 20 45 35 14 00 61 33 97 34 31 33 95
78 17 53 28 22 75 31 67 15 94 03 80 04 62 16 14 09 53 56 92
16 39 05 42 96 35 31 47 55 58 88 24 00 17 54 24 36 29 85 57
86 56 00 48 35 71 89 07 05 44 44 37 44 60 21 58 51 54 17 58
19 80 81 68 05 94 47 69 28 73 92 13 86 52 17 77 04 89 55 40
04 52 08 83 97 35 99 16 07 97 57 32 16 26 26 79 33 27 98 66
88 36 68 87 57 62 20 72 03 46 33 67 46 55 12 32 63 93 53 69
04 42 16 73 38 25 39 11 24 94 72 18 08 46 29 32 40 62 76 36
20 69 36 41 72 30 23 88 34 62 99 69 82 67 59 85 74 04 36 16
20 73 35 29 78 31 90 01 74 31 49 71 48 86 81 16 23 57 05 54
01 70 54 71 83 51 54 69 16 92 33 48 61 43 52 01 89 19 67 48
```

Main.py:

```
in_file = 'input.txt'

m = list(map(lambda line_str: list(map(int, line_str.split(' '))), open(in_file, 'r').read().split('\n')))

for line in m:
    print(' '.join(map(lambda num: str(num).rjust(2), line)))
print()

vertical_max = horizontal_max = main_diag_max = second_diag_max = 0

for line in range(17):
    for col in range(20):
        vertical_max = max(vertical_max, m[line][col] * m[line+1][col] * m[line+2][col] * m[line+3][col])

for line in range(20):
    for col in range(17):
        horizontal_max = max(horizontal_max, m[line][col] * m[line][col+1] * m[line][col+2] * m[line][col+3])

for line in range(17):
    for col in range(17):
        main_diag_max = max(main_diag_max, m[line][col] * m[line+1][col+1] * m[line+2][col+2] * m[line+3][col+3])

for line in range(3, 20):
    for col in range(3, 20):
        second_diag_max = max(second_diag_max, m[line][col] * m[line-1][col-1] * m[line-2][col-2] * m[line-3][col-3])


print('max vertical:          ', vertical_max)
print('max horizontal:        ', horizontal_max)
print('max main diagonal:     ', main_diag_max)
print('max secondary diagonal:', second_diag_max)
print('max result:            ', max(vertical_max, horizontal_max, main_diag_max, second_diag_max))
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What is the problem? Is the output wrong (and if so, what is it supposed to be)? Or do you get error messages?

Comment: Hello @DavidG. The question is right in the last line of the post ^^ "This is more of an educational question, I would like to at least know where i messed up." What did I do wrong?

Comment: @JJJ Hello, i have edited the question to make it more clear, there are no error but the output is wrong.

Comment: Identify the four-number-diagonal that produces the correct answer (hint : there's an 8x 9x 9x 8x diagonal towards the bottom-left). Consider what your code does such that it fails to pick out this value.

Comment: As far as I can see you are missing the diagonals in the form `m[line][col] * m[line+1][col-1] * m[line+2][col-2] * m[line+3][col-3]`

Comment: This seems like as good a time as any to [learn to debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). The likely problems here is that you're not checking all directions (correctly) or your bounds are incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second diagonal, your code should be:

```
for line in range(3, 20):
    for col in range(17):
        second_diag_max = max(second_diag_max, m[line  ][col  ] *
                                               m[line-1][col+1] *
                                               m[line-2][col+2] *
                                               m[line-3][col+3])
```

The problem was that instead of increasing `col` while decreasing `line` you were decreasing both. That was essentially checking main diagonal again, but from the opposite direction.

Comment: Thank you! I am so dumb for overlooking something so high school level.

Comment: These kinds of errors can happen to everyone. Probably even Euler himself had his dumb moments. :)